# How to populate json into dropdownlist for VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

I have this currency code api, https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json

How to populate json into dropdownlist for VueJs?

This is my code at the moment:

```js
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
            return {
                currencyFrom: null,
                loading: true,
                errored: false
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json")
                .then(response => (this.currencyFrom = response))
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.errored = true;
                })
                .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
  
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
        <select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code" v-else>
         <option v-for="currency in currencyFrom"  >{{ currency }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

It does manage to load the json but the dropdownlist is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the response.data `this.currencyFrom = response.data`

Refer to [axios response schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

```js
new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data() {
            return {
                currencyFrom: null,
                loading: true,
                errored: false
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json")
                .then(response => {this.currencyFrom = response.data})
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.errored = true;
                })
                .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
  
    <div id="app">
        <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
        <select class="form-control" name="currency_from_code" id="currency_from_code" v-else>
         <option v-for="currency in currencyFrom"  >{{ currency }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```